# What are the possible statuses of the nominator's account？

Tags: polkadot, minnominated

1. What are the possible statuses of the nominator's account？
2. The nominee's status is Retired，what is the status meaning?

link:
https://polkadot.subscan.io/nominator/148cJVXbMiv7kQnxUN7k9mAFdeLJv64JPehFT82CDuNHqbzb

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The posible [status](https://support.polkadot.network/support/solutions/articles/65000169209-what-does-active-inactive-waiting-mean-) for Nominators are three:

- **Active**: When at least one of your nominees are active, this nomination status will display as actively nominating
- **Inactive**: A set of nominations will be inactive when none of those nominees are participating in the current validator set (the set of validators currently elected to validate the network).
- **Waiting**: None of the nominees get into the active validator set this era. They may get into the active validator set in the future.

*Example:*

Suppose you have nominated five validator candidates, and three out of five were elected to the active validator set, then you should see two of your nominations as "waiting", and most likely one as "active" and the rest as "inactive".

The nominee's status is **Retired**，what is the status meaning?

Retired is a tag from [subscan](https://polkadot.subscan.io/nominator/148cJVXbMiv7kQnxUN7k9mAFdeLJv64JPehFT82CDuNHqbzb), I am not sure what means here. But you can check a couple of things to see the status of your account:

1. Open the [Staking Dashboard](https://staking.polkadot.network/#/nominate) and see the status of your account there.
2. Check the support article about [Why am I not receiving staking rewards?](https://support.polkadot.network/support/solutions/articles/65000170805)

Answer (score 0):

Based on feedback from the Subscan team, status `Retired` means that :

> *The nominator is no longer voting for or has no valid voting for
> active validators.*